# Replacing a Part of URL String in a Linux File With Another String

Tags: sed, string, search, replace, file-search

I have an HTML file on a Linux server that contains a long list of links. I am trying to edit this file as follows.

Find original occurrences of this type: `http://www.test.org/name`
Replace them with: `http://www.test.org/archive/name`

How can I do this? I have tried running:
`sed -i -e 's/http://www.test.org/name/http://www.test.org/archive/name/g' user.html`

However I get the following error back:

> sed: couldn't open file
>   ww.test.org/name/http://www.test.org/archive/name/g: No such file or
>   directory

I am aware that there are questions that answer similar queries, but they have not been of help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/` is default ***sed*** subexpression separator, use another one:

```
sed -i 's~http://www.test.org/name~http://www.test.org/archive/name~g' user.html
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Sincere gratitude. Worked like a charm.